# Making collection of posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I'm traing to make a collection of post in Ruby on Rails. A user has many posts, and a user can make collections of posts, both yours and others, and the collection belongs to a user. Here is my models:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
  belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :collections, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

But I'm not sure what to do from here, is my models correct or do I need a PostCollection model? How can I make the connection between the posts and collections?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, as described in the docs here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

You can look under the heading of "Many-to-many".

Comment: I did't know I could use has_and_belongs_to_many, should I use it in my Collection model like this?

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
  belongs_to :user
end